# Four monitors || Windows 10: mouse pointers stick to horizontal edge

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse

I recently switched to a four monitor setup and have an external display #2 *(main display)* just above my laptop monitor #1. When I try to move my mouse pointer between the monitors (highlighted in the image linked below) with (and without) a window, it sticks to the horizontal edge between them. This doesn't look like windows snap issue as windows does snapping in the verticle edges, and the pointer doesn't *literally* stick to the edge.

[image: Monitor setup]

The only way I've found around this issue is to move back and move across the edge with faster speed *(sort of like taking a run-up before a long jump)*

I'm seeing this issue since I turned to this setup a couple of weeks ago; anyway I'm running Windows 10 version 1903 (OS Build 18362.356). All monitors running 1920x1080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm as well that the issue (on Windows 10) is not fixed through registry entries or multi-tasking snap settings.

The issue is with the settings app auto-arrange / placement for muti-monitors that will sometimes look right but in fact cause the edges between some monitors to become "sticky" requiring higher mouse velocity to pass through.

In my case I have 6 monitors. A trial and error approach worked to fix the issue:

1. Take a problem scrren (5 in my case), overlap it with the adjacent that has the sticky edge (6)
2. Auto alignment breaks. Move the second screen back into place (6) overlapping to the left in my case.
3. Move the original one back (5), again overlapping.
4. Apply and Test. If not fixed, or if another edge has become a problem, repeat.

Images as follows:

Starting situation - looks right but red edge was sticking.
[image: Sticky Edge]

During trial and error fix:
[image: Trial and error fixing]

Now fixed - looks the same as the start but problem resolved.
[image: Fixed]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there was some gap between the monitors; removing the gap fixed the issue. It looks like if there's a gap between monitors, the behavior is as described above in the question.

@harrymc's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1484636/1092375) helped solve this, as changing the alignment created gap between another monitor that showed this behavior

The image below is the new displays arrangement, *for reference*. As we can see, there's almost no gap between the monitors #1 and #2
[new monitor setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzcmD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is one fix for this kind of problem:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`
- Set the DWORD value `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` to `1`.
  If that value does not exist, create it.
- Repeat for registry key
  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\EdgeUI`
- Restart Explorer, or logout and login, or reboot.

If this does not help, try to move monitors #1 and #2 a bit in their alignment.

Comment: there is no folder `EdgeUI` under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell`

Comment: Created it. But it did not work. Changing their alignment fixed the issue; but it created some gap between the adjoining monitor

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a 3 monitor setup, where when arranged using the Windows 10 "display settings" dialog some of the monitors would have a small gap between them. This would cause the mouse to "resist" when you would try to move between screens.

To fix it I used the "Set up multiple displays" option in the NVIDIA control panel, which allows you to eliminate the gap when the monitors are moved together.  If someone else with an NVIDIA graphics card has the same issue this might be the easier way than trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I give you what worked for me !

Since the bug comes from gap between screens, someone proposed to use re-arrangement from graphic card to delete gaps, but for example, with my 6 screens, i got 2 cards, so it doesn't help me,
so you just need to find a software to arrange monitors with more precision than windows, you can do it easily with DisplayFusion (it will tell you the distance in pixels between screens), hope it will help some of you.

3h lost on that because Microsoft refuses to solve a 5yo problem... Small indie company, can't blame them. And for the guy who can't handle a little ironic remark with no swearword on Microsoft and who's editing my messages, go live in your safe space or in China, your attitude is the antithesis of internet spirit.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to fix this issue is to remove all displays except my main one. Click 'Apply' so only the main one displays. Then add each display one-by-one, clicking 'Apply' each time I add a display.